the program error in rdma_get_cm_event encountered a segment_event
After restarting the machine, the program  error in rdma_get_cm_event encountered a segment_event.
enter image description here
enter image description here
The dynamic library version of librdmacm is 1.3.43.0
Has anyone encountered this problem before?
What can I do for this?

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when I ask a question?
